# How to save and restore the default prompt (when PS1 is not defined)?

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

In a shared cluster I work on, the environment settings for new accounts does not include a prompt setting, as far as I can tell.  In particular, `PS1` is not set.  And yet, when one logs into a new account, one gets a rather fancy prompt, featuring the username and the basename of the current directory.

I want to save this prompt (e.g. in an environment variable like `ORIGINAL_PS1`) before replacing it with my preferred prompt, so that I can restore it later if desired<sup>1</sup>.

How can I extract the prompt definition from the current prompt?

I am primarily interested in the answer to this question for `bash`, but if there's something analogous for `zsh`, please let me know.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I rather like the default prompt, but for everyday use I prefer to use a "`git`-aware" prompt.  That said, although I find the latter extremely helpful 99.999% of the time, ocassionally I `cd` to a `git` repo that is sufficiently messed up that it causes the prompt's generation to become unacceptably slow.  For those rare circumstances, I'd like to be able to run `export PS1=$ORIGINAL_PS1`.</sup>

Comment: Does `ORIGINAL_PS1=$PS1` work for you?

Comment: Just to comment on the very last bit of the question: `PS1` never has to be exported. It's purely a shell variable and no child processes of the shell needs to inherit it.

Comment: If `PS1` is _not set_, then that's probably not `bash`. what does echo $prompt say?

Comment: @Kusalananda: That observation actually solved the mystery: I had looked at the output of `printenv` for the prompt's definition, mistakingly thinking that it was exported.  Thank you all.  All your comments nailed it, each in a different way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORIGINAL_PS1=$PS1` would save the value of the primary prompt variable to a new variable.

The `PS1` variable is a shell variable that is not exported, i.e. it's not an environment variable that is inherited by child processes.

In the `zsh` shell, you may want to additionally save the "right primary prompt", `RPS1`, if that is used.  The primary prompt is called `PS1` in `zsh`, just as in `bash`.